# How to select only the last value in a query in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

How can I select on MySQL the last value of this result:

This is a result from query:

```
SELECT * from transaction WHERE transaction_id = 2
```

I just need the last value `3    300     2`

```
 bank_id    amount   transaction_id
  1           800         2
  3           50          2
  3           300         2
```

Answer (score 2):

If `bank_id` is not unique and you want to pick the record of highest amount first, you can try this one:

```sql
SELECT *
  FROM transaction
 WHERE transaction_id = 2
 ORDER BY bank_id DESC
        , amount DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0f75b/4)

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT *
FROM transaction
WHERE transaction_id = 2
ORDER BY bank_id desc
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: @winona - Your requirement is not specific. How do you pick #3 row (i.e. `3 300 2`) over the second row (i.e. `3 50 2`)? Any logic?

Answer (score 1):

**[Here is SQLFiddel Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3bc9/9)**

This Demo, selects Last Entry in `Transaction` table with your filter of `Transaction_ID = 2`.
Below is the Query which you can try.

```
select *,@curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_number 
  from Temp 
  Join (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
 where Transaction_id = 2
 order by row_number desc
 limit 1
```

Answer (score -1):

try out this..

```
SELECT *
  FROM transaction
 WHERE transaction_id = 2
 ORDER BY transaction_id DESC
 LIMIT 1
```